# Awesome not showing up in GDM?

Tags: linux, debian, awesome, gdm

I recently installed debian with xfce. Once installed, I upgraded to Debian testing and installed awesome, then rebooted. When I click the list of session options at GDM's login screen, the only options are xfce and "default" (xfce). Awesome has a desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions, but GDM can't find it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 5):

Last I looked, Debian's awesome package is kind of broken.  Go look at `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop` and see if there's a line in there reading `NoDisplay=true`.  If there is, change it to `false`, or delete the line entirely.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the missing `X-GDM-SessionRegisters=true` line.
After adding it under the correct .desktop file, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following [the official guide?](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome#Gnome_3.9_.2F_Ubuntu_13.10) You have to create/modify multiple files for this to work.